# Spring jdbcTemplate result set null error

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-data, resultset, jdbctemplate

I am designing an login form using spring Data Access. When the user enters the correct username and password the application works good, when he provides wrong username and password it is not taking to desired page. Here is my code:

login.jsp

```
<body>
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <form action="Registration" method="POST">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Username</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="username"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Password</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="password"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="login" value="Login"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

home.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Login Success</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

invalid.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Wrong UserCredentials</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

EmployeeDao

```
public class EmployeeDao {

JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate() {
    return jdbcTemplate;
}

public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
    this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
}

public EmployeeDao(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
    this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
}

public EmployeeDao()
{

}

public Register getRegisterationids(String uname,String password)
{
    String query="select * from registeration where uname=? and password=?";
    return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(query, new Object[] {uname,password},new Mapper());


}

private static final class Mapper implements RowMapper<Register>
{

    @Override
    public Register mapRow(ResultSet rs, int i) throws SQLException {
        Register r=new Register();
        r.setUname(rs.getString("uname"));
        r.setPassword(rs.getString("password"));
        return r;
    }

}
}
```

Registration.java

```
 if(request.getParameter("login")!=null)
    {
        String username=request.getParameter("username");
        String password=request.getParameter("password");
        /*Register rdao=(Register) ac.getBean("Register");
        rdao.setUname(username);
        rdao.setPassword(password);*/
        EmployeeDao regisdao=(EmployeeDao)ac.getBean("EmployeeDao"); 

        String uname1=regisdao.getRegisterationids(username, password).getUname();
        String password1=regisdao.getRegisterationids(username, password).getPassword();

        if(username.equals(uname1)&&password.equals(password1))
        {
            RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/home.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
        }

        else
        {
            RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/invalid.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
        }     
    }
```

When user enters correct user and password, it takes to home page. When user enters wrong username and password it throws an error, here is the error.

Error

```
StandardWrapperValve[Registration]: Servlet.service() for servlet Registration threw exception
org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 0
at       org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.requiredSingleResult(DataAccessUtils.java:71)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:804)
at com.Dao.EmployeeDao.getRegisterationids(EmployeeDao.java:52)
at com.Servlets.Registration.processRequest(Registration.java:99)
at com.Servlets.Registration.doPost(Registration.java:147)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusServletFilter.doFilter(TyrusServletFilter.java:295)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

]]

It shows result set is empty and expected is minimum 1..can anyone help to solve this..if wrong credentials the user should be taken to invalid.jsp...

Comment: That's expected. Read the javadoc of queryForObject(). Use queryForList() and check that the list isn't empty.

Comment: @JB Nizet Hi i am new to spring just now learning..can you help me how to do using list..